# open random pdf file from folder with coding (HTML main code used)

Tags: html, file, pdf, random, randomaccessfile

I have made this website where I collect recipes I can eat.

I would like to add a 'random' feature, where one of the recipes opens and I don't have to chose what to eat.

My knowlege of coding is limit (like a year of highschool making a HTML website limited) but I do now it has to be possible. I also learned very briefly about a random number generator option in PHP and Javascript.

The website is coded with HTML and Notepad++.

The files are all pdf typed and like this, '1.pdf' '2.pdf'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like

```
<script>
const max = 15; // the largest number in your PDF filename
const min = 1;
const rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
const pdf = document.createElement("embed");
pdf.width="800px"; // or what you want
pdf.height="2100px";
pdf.src=rnd+".pdf"
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  document.body.appendChild(pdf);
});
</script>
```